# Hide Registration And Login Form When User Is Logged In?

Tags: php

Hide Registration And Login Link When User Is Logged In?

I am new at PHP and I am having some difficulties.I have downloaded a login/register code. I also created a login/register link on my index page. What I want to do is to hide the Login/register links when I am logged on. How do I go about it?

Thank you

Comment: You should post the pieces of code you are using. Without that, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: You read the information from the cookie/session and then place code inside your page where yo define what's happening when the user is logged in.

Comment: dont forget to accept an answer by clicking on a tick on the left!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on your existing code but it should look something like this.

```
if($session->is_logged_in()){
    $user = User::find_by_id($session->user_id);
    $greeting = "Welcome {$user->username}! <a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
}else{
    $greeting = 'Welcome! <a href="login.php" title="Click to login">Login</a> or     <a href="register.php" title="click to register">register</a>';
}
```

Comment: where do I add this code you gave above?

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions.  store $_SESSION['username'] when someone logs in, clear it when they log out.

Check to see if $_SESSION['username'] exists when you want to print the login/register links.  If it doesn't exist, print them.  If it does, a user is already logged in.

Comment: Hi.login/register links are on my index page. What do you mean I should check if they exist.When I log in myself, I am greeted on the index page but Login/Register link will still be available. I would like them to go since it is personalized logged in. Thank you for the info

Comment: Thank you guys...I ended up doing this and it worked:<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))?>
  <?php if (($_SESSION['user_name']) !=""){?>
  Welcome:<? echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>  <a href="logout.php"> Logout</a>
      <? }?>

  <?php if (($_SESSION['user_name']) ==""){?>
        <a href="login.php" title="Click to login">Login</a> or     <a href="register.php" title="click to register">    register</a>
 
       <? echo $_SESSION['user_name'];}?>

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['user'] == "")
{
// your registration & login form here
}
```